# How to integrate MoneyBookers in Web application in PHP?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, skrill

I am creating a PHP website, and need to integrate MONEYBOOKERs as the payment gateway.

Need help in embedding the MoneyBookers gateway to my site. As I am using the test link (sandbox URL) which is:

> https://www.moneybookers.com/app/test_payment.pl

The problem which I am facing is, MONEYBOOKERs is not showing any transtion while testing it.

Please Help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Additionally, is this service existing after all?

Comment: @NicoHaase Hey Noco, this is a 10-year-old question. Not sure, if the service is still there or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the query is pretty old and I got the answer for it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I cover this topic in detail on a recent blog post of mine: **[How to automate Moneybookers (Skrill) using status_url (IPN)](http://wyday.com/blog/2011/automate-moneybookers-skrill-using-status_url-ipn-php-asp-net/)**. There is example code for PHP and C# and pictures illustrating the points:

1. Signup for a Moneybookers test account
2. Create a “secret word”
3. Create your own payment form (with your logo on the Moneybookers checkout page)
4. Verify the Moneybookers order

I won't cover every step here, because if I did my answer would take up several pages. However I will cover the 4th topic (verifying the Moneybookers order) because the answer currently on this page is riddled with problems (SQL injections, etc.). If you want in-detail instructions for every step then **[read my article](http://wyday.com/blog/2011/automate-moneybookers-skrill-using-status_url-ipn-php-asp-net/)**.

### Simple payment form on your website

I go into this in more detail [in the article](http://wyday.com/blog/2011/automate-moneybookers-skrill-using-status_url-ipn-php-asp-net/), but here's a simple payment form. Replace the bold values with your correct prices, app name, and Moneybookers email:

```
<form action="https://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="merchant-email@example.com"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="http://example.com/verify.php"/> 
  <input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="Total amount (e.g. 39.60)"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="Currency code (e.g. USD)"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="YourApp"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="detail1_text" value="License"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay!"/>
</form>
```

### Verifying the Moneybookers order

After a user has paid for your software, eBook, or other digital content you'll want to automatically verify the order and send what they ordered to their email address. In this example I mention **[creating a product key using LimeLM](http://wyday.com/limelm/)**, but you can really do anything.

In the example form above you set the location of script that will verify the Moneybookers orders:

```
<input type="hidden" name="status_url" value="http://example.com/verify.php"/>
```

The relevant part of the script is this:

```
// Validate the Moneybookers signature
$concatFields = $_POST['merchant_id']
    .$_POST['transaction_id']
    .strtoupper(md5('Paste your secret word here'))
    .$_POST['mb_amount']
    .$_POST['mb_currency']
    .$_POST['status'];

$MBEmail = 'merchant-email@example.com';

// Ensure the signature is valid, the status code == 2,
// and that the money is going to you
if (strtoupper(md5($concatFields)) == $_POST['md5sig']
    && $_POST['status'] == 2
    && $_POST['pay_to_email'] == $MBEmail)
{
    // Valid transaction.

    //TODO: generate the product keys and
    //      send them to your customer.
}
else
{
    // Invalid transaction. Bail out
    exit;
}
```

If you don't know how to set your secret word in Moneybookers, I explain how to do this in the " **[How to automate Moneybookers (Skrill) using status_url (IPN)](http://wyday.com/blog/2011/automate-moneybookers-skrill-using-status_url-ipn-php-asp-net/)**" article.

### Full payment example

If you're not keen on writing this code yourself then we have a fully built payment form for our **[LimeLM](http://wyday.com/limelm/)** customers. It's written for PHP, C#, and VB.NET and it's free for all our customers (even our free-users). So you can download it, integrate it into your site, and use it without paying us a cent.

Here's what the [payment selection page](http://wyday.com/limelm/help/how-to-generate-product-keys-after-order/) looks like:

[image]

Comment: Saying "it's not working" is not useful. See: [**"How to Report Bugs Effectively"** by Simon Tatham](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html) (of putty fame).

Answer (score 0):

Skrill is not using Moneybooker, now it has changed its test payment method. Documented here Page # 13 ( 2.3.2 ): https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/content/pdf/Skrill_Quick_Checkout_Guide.pdf

### Use below Merchant Test Accounts provided by Skrill:

[image]

### C# Code:

```
string url = "https://pay.skrill.com/?";

// Merchant Details
url += "pay_to_email=" + "demoqco@sun-fish.com";
url += "&recipient_description=" + "Your Project Title";
url += "&language=" + "EN";
url += "&transaction_id=" + "Your Transaction ID";
url += "&return_url=" + "Your Return URL After Successful Payment";

// Payment Details
url += "&amount=" + "Your Total Amount";
url += "&currency=" + "USD";
url += "&amount2_description=" + "Item Price:"; // item name
url += "&amount2=" + "Your Price Here"; // place price 
url += "&amount3_description=" + "Quantity:";
url += "&amount3=" + "Your Quantity Here";
url += "&amount4_description=" + "Tax:";
url += "&amount4=" + "Your Tax Here";
url += "&detail1_description=" + "Order ID:";
url += "&detail1_text=" + "Your Order_ID Here";
url += "&detail2_description=" + "Description:";
url += "&detail2_text=" + "Description of product";
url += "&detail3_description=" + "Product ID:";
url += "&detail3_text=" + "Your Product_ID here";
url += "&detail4_description=" + "Order Date:";
url += "&detail4_text=" + "Order Date here";

// Split Gateway
// If Payment method not set then skrill will automatically select methods in your country
//url += "&payment_methods=" + "WLT,ACC"; // Skrill, Credit/Debit Cards

// redirects to Skrill
Response.Redirect(url)
```

### For test payment use below test cards numbers after redirecting to Skrill:

[image]
**NOTE:** Amex uses four digits test CVV

Comment: hi i am integration skrill quick checkout but msid coming in return url is different from the one we are generation can you let us know what is the pattern for generating msid.

Comment: msid should be different in Skrill database it shouldn't be duplicate.