# Skrill Integration using php

Tags: php, skrill

I want to integrate Skrill to my website. I have tried their documentation but haven't managed to reach any goal. I have searched a lot but haven't found any libraries or proper documentation to do so. Need help with sample code. I don't want to do the process in my site i want it like paypal's express_checkout. Skrill will redirect to my given url. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show what you've tried and explain how it's not working.

Comment: Hi, since you've been around on this site long enough to earn some reputation, you've probably seen the kind of questions that get positive responses round here. This question is too vague ("I have tried but haven't managed" - **what** have you tried? **how** did those attempts fail?) and asking for too much (this isn't a code-writing service, or a directory of tutorials). You need to explain exactly where you've stuck, and show us some code that you've tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544016/how-to-integrate-moneybookers-in-web-application-in-php https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/templates/main/res/material/documents/pdf/getting-started/skrill-automated-payment-interface-manual-en.pdf https://www.skrill.com/fileadmin/templates/main/res/material/documents/pdf/getting-started/skrill-integration-manual-en.pdf