# Integrate skrill payment gateway in codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, payment-gateway, skrill

I am having so much difficulty in integrating **skrill payment gateway** in codeigniter. Although I have searched a lot and found information about other payment gateways like paypal, stripe etc. but I couldn't find any useful information about skrill payment gateway integration.

I have also took a look at the manual given by skrill but couldn't really understand. I found skrill api on github on this link: https://github.com/biju1984/skrill

I placed the api in third party folder and now i need to user to the skrill gateway form. And i don't know how to do that.

Anyone please suggest kind of library or flow wise integration that easy to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Put skrill library file in to your project `libraries folder` inside `application folder`.

**Step 2:**

Load skrill library in to your controller function:

```
$this->load->library('skrill_api');
```

If library inside folder then use, put main folder name of library:

```
$this->load->library('folder_name/skrill_api');
```

***Example:*** How to set default parameters to constructor:

```
$parameters = [
    'user_email' => 'demo@demo.com',
    'secret_word' => 'secret word',
    'merchant_id' => 'this is sample id',
    'mqi' => 'this is sample mqi'
];
$this->load->library('skrill_api', $parameters);
```

**Step 3:**

You can use skrill api using skrill object like this `$this->skrill_api`

***Example:***

```
/**
  * Used for creating the redirection URL for making payments
  *
  * @param array $args The parameters to be send to Skrill 
  * @param string $request_type The type of request charge / refund
  * @param string $sid The session id
  *
  */

// Pass your data in parameters
$response = $this->skrill_api->prepareRequest($args, $request_type, $sid);
```

**Note:** If you still facing issues after above step, you can checkout below details:

- Class name and file / library name should be same, and starts with capital letter:

  - **File name:** Skrill_api.php
  - **Class name:** Skrill_api
- For more details please refer:

  - [Skrill Home Integration Guide](https://www.skrill.com/en/business/integration/)
  - [Skrill PHP Library](https://github.com/biju1984/skrill)
  - [Skrill PHP API Library File - skrill_api.php](https://github.com/biju1984/skrill/blob/master/skrill_api.php)
  - [Also checkout Stackoverflow Question by Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473980/how-to-integrate-skrill-in-codeigniter)
  - [One More library by `ASHADUR ROB`](https://github.com/robengg/codeigniter-moneybookers-libraries/blob/master/skrill.php)

Comment: what you have suggested i have done this like till $parameters and loading libarary

Comment: so after user clicks on check out what should happen after loading library?

Comment: i have been over skrill integration guide but i couldn't follow so i came to this plate-form for simplicity

Comment: After click on checkout you can pass details of payment order into your request function means see `Step 3`..

Comment: Now its easy for you right, just pass parameters in to first parameter of this function `prepareRequest` that i have explained in `Step 3`